# How to hide links in HTML source code while using browser to get source code view?

Tags: javascript, html, security, url, encryption

Something like this `<a href="url">...</a>` in an HTML page can be get in the browser source code view when press F12. A HTML page exposes some interfaces and url in the browser source code view. Someone takes advantage of this to get the resource of urls and download resource without paying. I wonder how to encrypt the urls so that no one can download resources without paying.
I search for this question. I get the following solutions, but I think maybe they are not secure enough. I find that disabling some key such as F12, Shift+F10 can be a solution. The other way is to encrypting the HTML source code. The method I find is to use `escape`. I am new to JavaScript. I wonder how to use some crypto encryption methods, such as AES, MD5, to do this work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to this is entirely wrong.

If you don't want the user to have something, then *just don't give it to them*. Don't give it to them wrapped in some form of encryption.

If you don't want the link to work without the user paying then use **server side** code which has logic along the lines of:

```
if (!userHasPaid()) {
    redirect(sales_page);
    exit;
}
provideDownload();
```